# getElementById in 3 ways

Tags: javascript

I have an application that needs to retrieve a value out of a hidden input form field.  However, this application has a base page which calls another page that is in an iFrame and then it also can call itself inside another iFrame:

default.asp -> screen.asp (in iFrame)
screen.asp -> a new instance of screen.asp (in iFrame)

```
document.getElementById('focusValue').value
window.frames[0].document.getElementById('focusValue').value
parent.frames[arrVal].document.getElementById('focusValue').value
```

When I reference the hidden input form field from default -> screen I can use the standard `document.getElementById('focusValue').value;`.  Then when I'm in the 1st level iFrame I have to use `window.frames[0].document.getElementById('focusValue').value;`.  Then when I'm in the 2+ levels in an iFrame I have to use the `parent.frames[arrVal].document.getElementById('focusValue').value;`.

A common structure that I'm starting to see is this:

```
if(document.getElementById('focusValue') == undefined){
        window.frames[0].document.getElementById('focusValue').value = focusValue;
        console.log('1');
}else if((parent.frames.length -1) == arrVal){
        console.log('2');
        if (arrVal > 0) {
            parent.frames[arrVal].document.getElementById('focusValue').value = focusValue;
        }
}else{
    document.getElementById('focusValue').value = focusValue;
    console.log('3');
}
```

Now I can certainly do this but outside of writing a novel worth of comments I'm concerned with other programmers(or me 1 month from now) looking at this code and wondering what I was doing.

My question is there a way to achieve what I'm looking to do in a standard form?  I'm really hoping that there is a better way to achieve this.

Comment: That's why comments where invented. Document what you are doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you have each page do the work of finding the value you want by calling a method. Basically exposing a lookup interface. Then you only need to call a method on the target page from the parent page. Proper naming will help developers understand what is going on and using methods will simplify the logic.

Or if you only need to get the value from the parent page, then you could register a hook with each page in an iframe using a common interface. Each page can just call that hook to get the value. This prevents your complex logic of determining what level the page is. Something like

```
iframe1.GetValueHook = this.GetValue;
iframe2.GetValueHook = this.GetValue;
```

Then each page can just call

```
var x = this.GetValueHook();
```

If you have nested pages, you could make this recursive. If you need communication between all pages then use the same approach but with a registration process. Each page registers itself (and it's children) with it's parent. But if you need to do this then you should reevaluate your architecture.

Example:
**register.js**

```
var __FRAMENAME = "Frame1";
var __FIELDID = "fieldId";
var __frames = [];

function RegisterFrame(frame) {
    __frames.push(frame);

    for (var i = 0; i < frame.children.length; i++) {
        __frames.push(frame.children[i]);
    }

    RegisterWithParent();
}

function RegisterWithParent() {

    var reg = {
        name: __FRAMENAME,
        getvalue: GetFieldValue,
        children: __frames
    };

    if(parent != undefined && parent != this) {
        parent.RegisterFrame(reg);   
    }
}

function SetupFrame(name, fieldId) {
    __FRAMENAME = name;
    __FIELDID = fieldId;

    RegisterWithParent();
}

function GetFieldValue() {
    return document.getElementById(__FIELDID).value;
}

function GetValueFrom(name) {
    for (var i = 0; i < __frames.length; i++) {
        if (__frames[i].name == name) {
            return __frames[i].getvalue();
        }
    }

}
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="register.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

PAGE

<input type="hidden" id="hid123" value="123" />
<iframe id="frame1" src="frame1.html"></iframe>
<iframe id="frame2" src="frame2.html"></iframe>
<script type="text/javascript">
    SetupFrame("Index", "hid123");

    setTimeout(function () { //Only here for demonstration. Make sure the pages are registred
        alert(GetValueFrom("frame3"));
    }, 2000);
</script>
</body></html>
```

**frame1.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="register.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="hidden" id="hid" value="eterert" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    SetupFrame("frame1", "hid");
</script>
</body></html>
```

**frame2.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="register.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="hidden" id="hid456" value="sdfsdf" />
<iframe id="frame2" src="frame3.html"></iframe>
<script type="text/javascript">
    SetupFrame("frame2", "hid456");
</script>
</body></html>
```

**frame3.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="register.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="hidden" id="hid999" value="bnmbnmbnm" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    SetupFrame("frame3", "hid999");
</script>
</body></html>
```

This would be better if you can change it up to use a dictionary/hash tbale instead of loops.

Comment: I've never used/seen the GetValueHook property.  Do you have any links that explain it?  Will this work even if the iFrame is recursive (same page but given a different element id)?

Comment: It isn't a property, it would be a global function pointer declared by your script. I'll write a demo and post it

Comment: I'll try this out to see if I can implement this in my code.  Thanks for the example!

Comment: This just puts code all over the place, making it even harder to maintain. I would leave it all in one place.

Comment: @JTWebMan no, it's in a single script that's referenced by each page. Of course each page has to initialize itself. It would be WORSE to leave it all in a single page because he said that the field names can change per page so you would have to know about each page already and hardcode the names in the main page/script which means at minimum you have to edit two files. What happens when a designer changes the field name later on? Big mess that's hard to debug when you forget how it works. This way removes the complex if/else logic.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet will be to set varables named correctly so it's self documenting. Something like this...

```
var screenFrame = window.frames[0];
var screenFrame2 = parent.frames[arrVal];

var value = screenFrame2.document.getElementById('focusValue').value
```

This will make it easier to read.

Comment: I see where you are going with that, but unfortunately there could be up to 7 layers!  I know, it's ugly, but that is what I'm dealing with.

Comment: @JeffV Still better to leave it all on the one page and you could create a function to give you back the frame you need. 7 nested iframes is to much and should be re-designed quick!

Answer (score 0):

If you really must search frames for a given element, then you should just make your own function to do that and use that function everywhere.  Put a lot of comments in the function explaining why/what you're doing and give the function a meaningful name so it will be more obvious to future programmers looking at your code what you are doing or where they can look to find what you are doing.

```
function setValueByIdFrames(name) {
    if(document.getElementById(name) == undefined){
        window.frames[0].document.getElementById(name).value = name;
        console.log('1');
    } else if((parent.frames.length -1) == arrVal){
        console.log('2');
        if (arrVal > 0) {
            parent.frames[arrVal].document.getElementById(name).value = name;
        }
    } else {
        document.getElementById(name).value = name;
        console.log('3');
    }
}
```

Comment: I would agree except that this still requires a bunch of complex and brittle logic.

Comment: @ILovePaperTowels - if the location of a desired object is not known ahead of time (among frames), then it's the design of the application that is complex and brittle and this is the best one can do.  Obviously, it would be much better to fix the design of the application so one doesn't have to search multiple frames to find a given object.

Comment: @jfriend00 - I agree that this is probably the right solution (the one that would fix the issue in totality), however, this code is buried inside of a giant .js file that is several years old.  Doing what you suggest would require duplication of code which in my opinion would probably lead to other issues down the road (i.e. change something is one place and not in the other).  I certainly see your point though about the architecture.

Comment: @JeffV - The point of putting the logic in one central function is to avoid code duplication.  So, if you still think code has to be duplicated, then you need to abstract the function even more so that one central function serves all your needs.  I have no idea what this is really trying to do so can't help you with the further abstraction without a lot more explanation.